# NVIDIA Jetson TK1 Board and rviz indigo

Tags: ros, rviz, nvidia, jetson

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi

Has Anyone tested rviz in NVIDIA Jetson Board?

We are looking the most lightweight and compact hardware that allows run rviz in a properly way.

We have focused in this hardware, which has a NVIDIA GPU,  because I have read threads here that it suggests the use of NVIDIA GPU to avoid problems with rviz.

Best regard.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/206384/nvidia-jetson-tk1-board-and-rviz-indigo/) by [ctubio](https://answers.ros.org/users/22052/ctubio/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2015-04-01

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jaghvi](https://answers.ros.org/users/22520/jaghvi/) on 2015-05-22**:
Did you solve the issue I am having the same problem?
Seg Fault

**Comment by [ctubio](https://answers.ros.org/users/22052/ctubio/) on 2015-05-25**:
Hi jaghvi,

In fact we don´t have the board. We were waiting any user experience about this one.

I see that you have some problems. If you fix the problem please let me know.

Best regards

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2015-05-25**:
@jaghvi: if you need help, please ask a new question instead of posting an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

We've got rviz running on a Jetson TK1, but found issues with the version of libpcre (which libogre depends on) that Ubuntu Trusty ships with. We ended up installing libpcre 1:8.35 from Utopic.

---

Originally posted by [esteve](https://answers.ros.org/users/4526/esteve/) with karma: 89 on 2015-06-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I did not explicitly required rviz on Jetson, I mitigated the problem by running rviz on my laptop and communicated between my laptop and jetson over ethernet/internet. That is, Jetson acts as a master computer which runs ROS and you can connect as many computers you want over the same network and all the nodes will be talking to each other.

---

Originally posted by [jaghvi](https://answers.ros.org/users/22520/jaghvi/) with karma: 11 on 2015-06-02

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1